# Send emails with multiple files from one cell

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am new here and looking for experts to help with the following:
I have multiple filepaths in cell separated with commas that I need to send by email to respective recipients.

[image]

The problem is that my code is referring - Runtime Error '-2147024773 (8007007b, Filename or directory is not valid.
However, when I put single file in a cell, that works:

```
Sub Preview()

Dim SendTo As String
Dim ToMSg As String
Dim Attachment As Variant
Dim Subj As String
Dim Item As Variant

i = 2

Do

SendTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "F")
ToMSg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "I")
Attachment = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "J").Value, ",")
Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "H")
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutlookMail
.To = SendTo
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = Subj
.body = ToMSg
 For Each Item In Attachment
.Attachments.Add Item
Next
.display
    
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

i = i + 1

Loop Until Cells(i, "A").Value = ""


End Sub
```

What seems to go wrong?

I searched for solution online and tried using the Split() method but it is not working

Comment: Is there a newline character in the cells, in addition to the comma?

Comment: Try `Attachment = Split(Replace(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "J").Value, vbLf, ""), ",")` to remove any newlines, and `.Attachments.Add Trim(Item)` to take care of leading/trailing spaces.  You could also use `Dir(Item)` to check whether the file exists before trying to add it.

Comment: Is there a way to say thank you digitally? Kind of a "like" or something?

Comment: Good to hear it's working now.  I've posted my comments as an answer, so please go ahead and click the checkmark to Accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly there are newline characters in the cells, in addition to the comma. Try

`Attachment = Split(Replace(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "J").Value, vbLf, ""), ",")`

to remove any newlines, and

`.Attachments.Add Trim(Item)`

to take care of leading/trailing spaces.

You could also use `Dir(Item)` to check whether the file exists before trying to add it.